# Return statement not working with Stripe

Tags: javascript, callback, return, stripe-payments

I am calling a function to perform a Stripe API request, but when I return a bool nothing happens. The function gets called but nothing inside the if statement gets called, instead the else statement gets called.

```
if(performStripeAction() == true) {
    console.log("action performed"); //does not get printed
} else {
    console.log("error transferring"); //prints error transferring
}

function performStripeAction() {
var psaret;
  console.log("about to start transfer");
  stripe.transfers.create(
    {
      amount: 10000,
      currency: 'usd',
      destination: act_xxxxx
    }, function(err, transfer){
      if(!err){
        console.log("no error"); //prints no error
        psaret = true;
      }else{
        console.log("error");
        psaret = false;
      }
      console.log("the bool is " + psaret); //prints true
      return psaret;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  stripe.transfers.create({ 
       amount: 10000, 
       currency: 'usd',   
       destination: act_xxxxx },{stripe_account: String(accountId)},    
      function(error, transfer) {
       if (error) {
           // Transfer failed
        return console.log("error transferring"); //prints error transferring
        }

   // Transfer succeeded.You can then use "transfer" object to cal  another  function
   console.log("action performed"); 
  });
```

Comment: It looks like the whole entire function needs a return statement. The return statement inside the `function(error, transfer)` is returning for that function not the `performStripeAction()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply have the Stripe API call [return a promise](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#api-overview):

```
performStripeAction()
.then(function(ret) {
    if (ret)
       console.log('action performed');
    else
       console.log('error transferring')
}); 


function performStripeAction() {
    var psaret;
    console.log("about to start transfer");
    return stripe.transfers.create(
      {
        amount: 10000,
        currency: 'usd',
        destination: act_xxxxx
      }
    ) 
    .then(function(transfer){
         console.log("no error"); //prints no error
         psaret = true;
         return psaret;
    })
    .catch(function(err)){
         console.log("error");
         psaret = false;
         return psaret;
    });
}
```

Comment: action performed or error transferring does not print, but no error does.

Comment: Are you calling performStripeAction().then(function(ret) {...}) ?
I edited the answer so you can see how to do that.

Comment: Yes I did do that